# SAS teradata connection

Tags: sas, teradata

I am using following query to connect SAS with Teradata:

```
proc sql;
    connect to Teradata (server = ‘WML’ user = ‘******’  password = ‘*******’ mode = Teradata );
quit;
```

But I am getting following error:

> ERROR : Teradata connection: TheUserId, Passowrd or Account is invalid

I have am able to work in Teradata with same username and password. Why am I getting this error

Comment: What is your authentication mechanism in SAS compared to your other means of working in Teradata?

Comment: Did you really use those "ugly" quote characters instead of normal single quote (`'`) or double quote(`"`) characters?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify logdb parameter too. It is a database you have write access rights to. So just try putting logdb="yourdatabase" after the mode.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rob paller  asked you in comment section, what is your authentication mechanism, I seriously doubt it might be ldap, try using your username(whatever it as @ldap) as shown in below example

```
   proc sql;
   connect to Teradata (server = ‘WML’
   user = ‘myusernamee@LDAP’  password     = ‘*******’ mode = Teradata );
   quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a macro variable with connection string, so later on you only have 1 line of code to update if needed. The code below should work with you:

```
%let tdconnection=%unquote(user=******  pwd="*******" MODE=Teradata   tdpid=WML); 
proc sql;
connect to Teradata (&tdconnection );
/*your SQL here*/
disconnect from Teradata;  
quit;
```